# Is there a replace funtion fo one part of the formula in excel?

Tags: excel

I have a 200 day inventory stock simulation in excel with the cell formula be
=IF(OR(B12=1),5,0)

5 is the re-order quantity.
How do I change it to any number anytime I want without doing it manually?

Comment: Put the number in a cell and let the function refer to the cell. Actually, Excel rule #1: Never put data in a formula. Data belong on the sheet and formulas manipulate them.

Comment: What @Variatus says is probably a basic concept of excel to know.
In the place of 5, you should write a reference to a cell and write wanted numbers in that cell.